# MYSQL Group in one table and multiply with numbers from another table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables as below:
goods_in:

```
in_id|pid|in_num|in_date
1     1001 10    2020-06-28
2     1002 20    2020-06-28
3     1001 20    2020-05-25
......
```

stock:

```
stock_id|pid|num|price
 1      1001   10   5
 2      1002   15   6
 3      1003   20   7
...
```

The "goods_in" table stores the records that all goods come into warehouse, the pid in this table is the same as in table "stock" which is the product ref code. There will be multiple records for each product in "goods_in" table.
The "stock" table stores all the SKU we are holding and the current stock level as well as the product cost.
What I'm trying to do is:

1. Group by pid AND date (Year+Month) from "goods_in" so I get sub-total number of goods booked-in in each month.
2. Multiple sub-total with stock.price.
3. Get total amount of above, something like SUMPRODUCT in excel.
4. Exports to html table or excel.

I've tried several answers from SO with GROUP BY/ROLLUP/JOIN, and apparently I haven't made it right as expected. I can make this simple if I just add a cost column to the "goods_in" table but that would make it untidy.

I'm still on my learning curves with MYSQL, forgive me if this looks simple to you guys.

Thanks.

Ken

Comment: given your sample data, what output do you expect?  you don't say what fields you want or what you mean by total

Comment: Thanks @ysth, I've edited with updates to make it clearer, hopefully.

Comment: so each pid, month, and a total of all the price*in_num for that pid/month?  having you show what you want would be much easier than guessing

Comment: What SQL statement(s) have you tried so far, and what about the results is not what you want?

Comment: @kmoser I tried SELECT pid, SUM(stock.price * num) AS total
FROM goods_in
GROUP BY pid and obviously the "num" is incorrect in this sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to know for sure what you want, but it sounds something like this:

```
select
    pid,
    year(in_date) as year,
    month(in_date) as month,
    sum(goods_in.in_num * stock.price)
from goods_in
join stock using (pid)
group by pid, year, month
```

For exporting to html or excel, you are best off asking a separate question.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. It's almost what I wanted, except for the price is not in goods_in table. I also need to group by the year as well so we don't get same month of different year. Data exporting is fine, I can deal with that.

Comment: yes, price isn't in goods_in; that's why it needs to join stock.  and my "month" includes the year.  but I'll update it to be more clear

Comment: Thank you @ysth, I'll give it a run and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Worked it out based on your solution, thank you@ysth

Comment: @Godinall if it worked for you, could you upvote my answer?